# Edittext not filling parent

Tags: android, xml, styles

so I am trying to make a textbook with a submit button using the table layout for my fragment but the issue is the textbook is becoming the size of the button. It is not filling the width

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textUri" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_as"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="As" />

        </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the entire column's width is defined by the subsequent Button's width. This is because that Button is the widest in the column.

Within your `TableLayout` element, you want to mark the first column (index 0) as stretchable by declaring `android:stretchColumns`.

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:stretchColumns="0">
```